# Unable to get LinkedIn access token when using devise and omniauth-linkedin-oauth2

Tags: devise, linkedin-api, omniauth

I am using devise and omniauth-linkedin-oauth2 to sign in users and I am trying to get some basic API access at the time of the login.

User gets logged in properly. But when I try to use the same code from callback to get an access token, that request is failing.

Here's the code I am using to get access token after user signs in with linkedin + omniauth -

```
code = params[:code]
uri = URI('https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken')
        res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                                  code: auth_code,
                                  redirect_uri: 'https://devlopmentsite.com/users/auth/linkedin/callback',
                                  client_id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                                  client_secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

I get the following error in response -

```
"{\"error\":\"invalid_request\",\"error_description\":\"Unable to retrieve access token: appid/redirect uri/code verifier does not match authorization code. Or authorization code expired. Or external member binding exists\"}"
```

However if the same code block with same client_id and client_secret are working properly when I am doing it without omniauth. So there is another button for use to provide linkedin api access after logging in - that is independent of omniauth.

The same workflow and code block work properly there. But they are failing when used with omniauth, is there any reason for this? Or am I doing something wrong?